# Cut and paste active row from one table to another table on different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Ok. This sounds simple enough but...I have a spreadsheet with a userform that tracks my Purchase orders. When I search the PO# from my userform the data is returned to a listbox. I click the listbox entry I want and the information populates the userform text boxes. I want to click a button called "reconcile" to cut that record from the current sheet "Purchase Orders" the table name is "T-INV") and paste it to Sheet "Reconciled" the table is "Reconciled" the tables are identical in columns. I would also like the row that was cut to be deleted from the "Purchase order" sheet.

I know that sounds complicated but I just want to cut and paste the selected PO from one sheet/table to another using a command button. I can provide code if needed but there are a lot of buttons. Everything I need the form to do it does. I just need a macro or VBA code to cut the active row and paste it in the other table on the reconciled sheet. The Macro recorder doesn't work for this. I just want the values pasted not the formulas from the original table.

```
Private Sub CmdRecon_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 25) = "y" Then
            Range("a" & i & ":Y" & i).Copy Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Cells(i, 25).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but rule of thumb, if you don't know where to start, Stack Overflow isn't a good place to do so - "I need code that does XYZ" usually isn't well received. Have you tried recording an actual paste-special/values operation?

Comment: I did try that but because I want to cut the active row using my userform, the record macro didn't work right. I can upload a sample workbook if that helps. Is that even allowed?

Comment: I wouldn't download some random macro-enabled workbook, no. But if you included the actual non-working code you've tried, it could go a long way.

Comment: This is the code I am currently working with but it works off of cell value. It also just pastes it over, I want it to just paste the value of each cell.

'CODE' Private Sub CmdRecon_Click()

   Dim i As Long

   For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 25) = "y" Then
   Range("a" & i & ":Y" & i).Copy Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 
  1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
   Cells(i, 25).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Next
 
     End Sub
'code'

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Range("a" & i & ":Y" & i).Copy Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
> ```

You're using `Range.Copy`, which copies *everything* about that range.

You want to copy the range to the clipboard, and then [`PasteSpecial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) on the target range:

```
Range("a" & i & ":Y" & i).Copy
Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: A couple things. Thanks to whomever fixed my post with the code. I couldn't get it to display right. Next thanks you for your response. That is very helpful. The code looks for a "y" in column 25. I would prefer it just use the active row from when I select it from my listbox.

Comment: Then don't use a loop and `i` with `ActiveCell.Row`

Comment: Like This?:
'code'
Private Sub CmdRecon_Click()

    Dim i As Long

    i = ActiveCells.row.End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1 
    Range("a" & i ).Copy Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 
    activeCells.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub